# Conditional Routing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Let say I have my `user` controller and there are `action_index()`, `action_login()`, `action_logout()` `action_profile($userid)`  methods in it. I want to make a routing that

```
www.mysite.com/user/xxxx
```

checks the `xxxx` part of the url and if it is not one of (login,logout,index) it calls `action_profile(xxxx)` method.

Now I am doing it like this:
my routing routs all `www.mysite.com/user/xxxx` type of requests to `action_index` and it checks whether `xxxx` is a method name or not. If it is not a method name it calls `action_profile(xxxx)`

However, I think it is possible in a better way. How can I do it better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking. Routes in laravel are on a first match basis.

So you could just add the following to your `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('user/(:num)', 'user@profile');
Route::controller('user');
```

The first line is for routing `user/xxx` to `action_profile()` in user controller where `xxx` is any numerical value. While the second will maps any other URI (`user/***/***`) to corresponding user controller's methods. That means it automatically maps `user/login` to `action_login()`, `user/register` to `action_register()` and so on.

Comment: your code is right. Edited to add some explanation about what does Route::controller() do. Hope it will approved soon.

Comment: The only problem here is that it opens up `user/profile/{id}` as well, which will be a duplicate of `user/{id}`. Some people prefer to avoid doing things like this as it can be bad for search engine optimization.

Comment: @JasonLewis you're right. I don't think user/* stuff should be recongized by SEO anyway so this would be a no-issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you avoid using `Route::controller()` in this instance. While it can be fine to use in some cases, for what you're after it would be better to map to the routes.

You could do it like so.

```
Route::get('user', 'user@index');
Route::get('user/(:num)', 'user@profile');
Route::get('user/(:any)', 'user@(:1)');
```

Or you could be a little stricter with your last route.

```
Route::get('user/(login|logout)', 'user@(:1)');
```

My reasoning for recommending you avoid `Route::controller()` is that it does create duplicates to some content. For example, `yoursite.com/user` will by duplicated on `yoursite.com/user/index`. This can be bad for search engine optimization.

Mapping to your actions gives you that extra flexibility and control.